# Can you reference a remote resource in a Grails datasource config file?

Tags: grails, configuration, datasource

I'd like to configure a Grails datasource's url property from a remote resource. (I'd like to keep some information in etcd).  e.g. Something like this:

```
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def urlConfig = jsonSlurper.parseText(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:2379/v2/keys/dataSource/url").text)
dataSource {
    ....
    url = ${urlConfig.node.value}
}
```

If I println the url value in the config file when starting the app, it shows the expected value.  But the following error occurs when using the dynamic approach:

> Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException:
>   Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLException: Driver:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@44a3eec9 returned
>   null for URL:jdbc:h2:mem:grailsDB;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000

So it looks like this approach won't work without modification.  Is that right?  i.e. Does Grails currently only support the database URL value being configured as a static String in the datasource config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can.  My problem above was a dumb syntax error...setting the value to `url = ${urlConfig.node.value}` instead of `url = urlConfig.node.value`

Answer (score 0):

We load external datasource config file like this, maybe you can try.

DataSource.groovy:

```
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils as PLU
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource as CPR
...
try {
    ConfigObject properties = new ConfigSlurper().parse(PLU.loadProperties(new CPR('DataSource.properties')))
    dataSource.merge( properties.dataSource )
    hibernate.merge( properties.hibernate )
} catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e){}
```

DataSource.properties:

```
dataSource.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl
...
hibernate.properties.xxxx = dddd
```